# How to use FreeRadius?

Tags: ldap

Could anybody tell me the steps to run and configure a FreeRadius on Ubuntu. I've installed it through Software center. Also let me whether lamp-server is required? I don't want to have a LDAP directory, just a local set of few usernames/password.

Answer (score 0):

I have just what you need. Here my post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12292058#post12292058

it works 100%

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you provide detail on the link here please. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.